# Swift sorting array of structs by string double

Tags: swift

I have an array of structs that I am looking to sort from highest to lowest based on Double value stored as a String. This is the way I'm currently doing it:

```
users.sort { (lhs, rhs) in return lhs.weekFTC > rhs.weekFTC }
```

This is returning the order based on the first number rather than the full number. Is there a better way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Why do you store a `Double` as a `String`? And what happens when the values are equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the `weekFTC` string to a `Double` and then compare, like so:

```
users.sort { (lhs, rhs) -> Bool in
    let lhsVal = Double(lhs.weekFTC) ?? 0
    let rhsVal = Double(rhs.weekFTC) ?? 0

    return lhsVal > rhsVal
}
```

---

Comparing strings directly does a lexicographical comparison.

Example:

```
var array = ["111", "e3", "22"]

array.sort { (lhs, rhs) -> Bool in
    return lhs > rhs
}
print(array) //["e3", "22", "111"]
```

So we should see if the string can be made into a number and **then** sort.
This time it will do a numeric comparison, like so:

```
var array = ["111", "e3", "22"]

array.sort { (lhs, rhs) -> Bool in
    let lhs = Double(lhs) ?? 0
    let rhs = Double(rhs) ?? 0
    return lhs > rhs
}
print(array) //["111", "22", "e3"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a comparator which is able to handle numeric strings

```
users.sort { $0.weekFTC.compare($1.weekFTC, options: .numeric) == .orderedDescending }
```